# Ruby fileutils: Forcing symlink creation from within cp_r

Tags: ruby

I'm attempting to recursively copy directories with Ruby's cp_r method in fileutils. However, it crashes in the (silly but out of my control) case where in the directory I copy there is a file and a symbolic link to that file. I get the following error:

```
/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/fileutils.rb:1223:in `symlink': File exists - real_file_name or symbolic_link_filename (Errno::EEXIST)
```

Now, I might be wrong, but it seems like something that symlink's :force option should take care of; however, cp_r cannot take a :force option, and I see no way to make it pass that option to its internal calls to symlink. Also, catching the EEXISTS error doesn't seem to be a solution since the run of cp_r would still be interrupted.

Is there a clean way to get around this problem?

Comment: It's not an answer, but http://tickets.opscode.com/browse/CHEF-833 seems relevant.

Comment: please share the code part,which gives you the trouble. We can't guess and reproduce the same in our desktop,rather looking into your code,may help you to unstuck from the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`FileUtils.cp_r`](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.2.2/libdoc/fileutils/rdoc/FileUtils.html#method-c-cp_r) and pass it the option `remove_destination: true` to accomplish this.